# Joomla Fatal error out of memory with debug_backtrace()

Tags: php, debugging, joomla

Today our website anattorneyforyou.com started getting fatal memory timeout errors. the exact error message was this:

"Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32 bytes) in /www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/exception.php on line 117"

The problem is not enough memory, it is the function debug_backtrace() that is creating an infinite loop which is using up all the memory. I found some info on this webpage: http://www.petermac.com/joomla-out-of-memory-error-with-exception-php/ that told me to change the function from debug_backtrace to debug_print_backtrace. When I did this I could see the infinate loop I was ablet o grab the first 20 lines or so here is the output:

```
#0 JException->__construct(Unable to load application: site, 500, 1, , 1) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:136] 
#1 JError::raise(1, 500, Unable to load application: site, , 1) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:171] 
#2 JError::raiseError(500, Unable to load application: site) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:143] 
#3 JApplication::getInstance(site, Array (), J) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/factory.php:46] 
#4 JFactory::getApplication(site) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/index.php:32] 

#0 JException->__construct(Application Instantiation Error, 500, 1, , 1) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:136] 
#1 JError::raise(1, 500, Application Instantiation Error, , 1) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:171] 
#2 JError::raiseError(500, Application Instantiation Error) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/factory.php:43] 
#3 JFactory::getApplication() called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:546] 
#4 JError::customErrorPage(JException Object ([level] => 1,[code] => 500,[message] => Unable to load application: site,[info] => ,[file] => ,[line] => 0,[function] => ,[class] => ,[type] => ,[args] => Array (),[backtrace] => ,[_errors] => Array ())) 
#5 call_user_func(Array ([0] => JError,[1] => customErrorPage), JException Object ([level] => 1,[code] => 500,[message] => Unable to load application: site,[info] => ,[file] => ,[line] => 0,[function] => ,[class] => ,[type] => ,[args] => Array (),[backtrace] => ,[_errors] => Array ())) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:530] 
#6 JError::handleCallback(JException Object ([level] => 1,[code] => 500,[message] => Unable to load application: site,[info] => ,[file] => ,[line] => 0,[function] => ,[class] => ,[type] => ,[args] => Array (),[backtrace] => ,[_errors] => Array ()), Array ([0] => JError,[1] => customErrorPage)) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:143] 
#7 JError::raise(1, 500, Unable to load application: site, , 1) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:171] 
#8 JError::raiseError(500, Unable to load application: site) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:143] 
#9 JApplication::getInstance(site, Array (), J) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/factory.php:46] #10 JFactory::getApplication(site) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/index.php:32] 

#0 JException->__construct(Application Instantiation Error, 500, 1, , 1) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:136] 
#1 JError::raise(1, 500, Application Instantiation Error, , 1) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:171] 
#2 JError::raiseError(500, Application Instantiation Error) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/factory.php:43] 
#3 JFactory::getApplication() called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:546] 
#4 JError::customErrorPage(JException Object ([level] => 1,[code] => 500,[message] => Application Instantiation Error,[info] => ,[file] => ,[line] => 0,[function] => ,[class] => ,[type] => ,[args] => Array (),[backtrace] => ,[_errors] => Array ())) 
#5 call_user_func(Array ([0] => JError,[1] => customErrorPage), JException Object ([level] => 1,[code] => 500,[message] => Application Instantiation Error,[info] => ,[file] => ,[line] => 0,[function] => ,[class] => ,[type] => ,[args] => Array (),[backtrace] => ,[_errors] => Array ())) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:530] 
#6 JError::handleCallback(JException Object ([level] => 1,[code] => 500,[message] => Application Instantiation Error,[info] => ,[file] => ,[line] => 0,[function] => ,[class] => ,[type] => ,[args] => Array (),[backtrace] => ,[_errors] => Array ()), Array ([0] => JError,[1] => customErrorPage)) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:143] 
#7 JError::raise(1, 500, Application Instantiation Error, , 1) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:171] 
#8 JError::raiseError(500, Application Instantiation Error) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/factory.php:43] 
#9 JFactory::getApplication() called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:546] 
#10 JError::customErrorPage(JException Object ([level] => 1,[code] => 500,[message] => Unable to load application: site,[info] => ,[file] => ,[line] => 0,[function] => ,[class] => ,[type] => ,[args] => Array (),[backtrace] => ,[_errors] => Array ())) 
#11 call_user_func(Array ([0] => JError,[1] => customErrorPage), JException Object ([level] => 1,[code] => 500,[message] => Unable to load application: site,[info] => ,[file] => ,[line] => 0,[function] => ,[class] => ,[type] => ,[args] => Array (),[backtrace] => ,[_errors] => Array ())) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:530] 
#12 JError::handleCallback(JException Object ([level] => 1,[code] => 500,[message] => Unable to load application: site,[info] => ,[file] => ,[line] => 0,[function] => ,[class] => ,[type] => ,[args] => Array (),[backtrace] => ,[_errors] => Array ()), Array ([0] => JError,[1] => customErrorPage)) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:143] 
#13 JError::raise(1, 500, Unable to load application: site, , 1) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:171] 
#14 JError::raiseError(500, Unable to load application: site) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/application/application.php:143] 
#15 JApplication::getInstance(site, Array (), J) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/factory.php:46] #16 JFactory::getApplication(site) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/index.php:32] 

#0 JException->__construct(Application Instantiation Error, 500, 1, , 1) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:136] #1 JError::raise(1, 500, Application Instantiation Error, , 1) called at [/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/libraries/joomla/error/error.php:171] 
#2 JError::raiseError(500, Application Instantiation Error) called at
```

I was hoping someone familiar with joomla might be able to tell me what is going wrong here.

Thank you in advance for any help you might be able to give.

Ryan

Comment: What changed? Was there an update on your server?  Did you try the advice to truncate your session table? Also, not that this is a fix but you shouldn't have debugging on in a production site. Also please give the exact Joomla version and php version.

Comment: Hello, That is the weird part nothing has changed I have not made any updates to the Joomla files in over two years. This just started happening today. I am not sure how I Truncate the session table or turn off debugging mode. the version is old it is Version 1.5.22 and php 5.3.8

Comment: all Debuging was and is turned off.

Comment: But did anything happen on your server? Is there a chance it updated PHP? To truncate the table you go to phpmyadmin or whatever you have and just delete all the rows in the session table or use the truncate command ... don't delete the table, just the rows.

Comment: the PHP version is still the same no updates that I know of. Also there is only 4 rows on jos_sessions. I dont think that has anything to do with the infinate loop or mememory time out. Most of the errors say something about "unable to load application" when trying to do some of the functions like JException, JError::raiseError, JError::handleCallback ect.

Comment: Are you self hosted or did you ask your host?  You'd be surprised about the session table and the problems it can cause.  It's not about the number of rows, it's about corruption in the data. You may also want to try a repair on your database (usually you can do this through your host's control panel).    Are you having backend problems also or just front end?

Comment: Can you make sure you have an error page in your template or the default error page?

Comment: The site is hosted but I do have access to php.ini and MySql. I truncated jos_sessions and optimized the table still no effect on the problem. What I think is happening on line 117 in the error/exception.php the function debug_backtrace() is creating a infinite loop which is eating up all the memory. look at the log file I listed in my post above it keeps generating the same 5 errors in forever loop. the first error message is "" JException->__construct(Unable to load application: "". this is referencing the object JException and saying it is unable to load.

Comment: Yes, but the point is that it was not happening before. You can make it die after one interation but it's not the cause of the problem. Please paste what is at this line: `/www/anattorneyforyou.com/htdocs/index.php:32`  Does it really not have quotes?